# How can I control amount zoom effect in Photoshop's animation timeline?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

I've discovered the [Timeline in Photoshop CS6](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-timeline-animations.html). This allows one to create animated presentations of photographs.

I've selected part of a photo, cut it, and placed it on another layer above the base layer. I've then repaired the original base layer to replace the cut pixels using the spot healing brush.

I now want to animate by zooming into the base layer while the top layer remains stationary.

I can do this fine, but **I can't find a way to control the amount of zoom** — there are no controls for this I can see. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you move it there please @MichaelClark ?

Comment: Only a moderator can do that.

Comment: I am also not a moderator.

Answer (score 2):

Found [the answer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ja7uC7qbreA).

If I click on the right arrow before the timeline layer name, it opens like:
[image]

If I select the last frame, press CTRL + T (on Windows) I can then resize the final size of the image in the zoom sequence.